# laravel socialite class ServiceProvider not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am not really sure what went wrong, but i was trying to get socialite to work by following the instructions on https://socialiteproviders.netlify.com/ but it didnt work.

so i googled more and followed the instructions on https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/socialite which seems to be fine. I could connect to the google api but had some other errors.

so i kinde deleted the entry in the config/app.php, becuase it was not wirtten and used in the 2nd instruction

after some time, i tried again and i only get this error:

```
Class 'SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider' not found
```

also if i try this commands

```
composer update
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
```

i also get the error

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:                                                          
Class 'SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider' not found
```

how to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

Please remove already installed socialite and install it again.
[Follow this link, It is the best way to setup socialite in laravel](https://www.sitepoint.com/easily-add-social-logins-to-your-app-with-socialite/)

Comment: i removed socialite via "composer remove laravel/socialite". It got removed, but the same error with "Class 'SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider' not found
" still came. I am still gonna try to reinstall socialite following your provided link